# ASP.NET IIS Web.Config file - Prevent firewall bypass

Tags: asp.net, iis, firewall

I am using an ASP provider and pointing my IIS-based ASP domain to a firewall provider using nameservers.  The firewall providers suggested that I disable attempts to bypass Web.Config security setting by editing editing the .htaccess file, assuming I used Apache.  However, ASP uses IIS.  I did notice that for Apache, you only need to modify .htaccess with, for example, the following code:

```
<FilesMatch ".*">
    Require ip XXX.XX.XXX.X/23
    Require ip YYY.YY.YYY.Y/22

(MORE IP ADDRESS)

</FilesMatch>
```

**UPDATE**

You can either use the IIS Manager or Web.Config to set IP address-based access control.  Originally, I used IIS Manager to set the IP address access, but now want to transition to Web.Config only with the following file contents:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
                <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="https://www.myweb.org/" />
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
        <security>
            <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
                <clear/>
                <add ipAddress="127.0.0.1" allowed="true"/>
                <add ipAddress="11.111.111.11" allowed="true"/>
                <add ipAddress="222.22.22.22" allowed="true"/>
            </ipSecurity>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;"/>
    </appSettings>
        <location path="Default WebSite">
        </location>
    <system.web>
          <webServices>
        <protocols>
          <add name="HttpGet"/>
          <add name="HttpPost"/>
        </protocols>
      </webServices>
          <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
          <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
                 <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
                </customErrors>
    </system.web>
    <system.codedom>
    </system.codedom>
        <startup>
               <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
        </startup>
</configuration>
```

Access control now does seem kind of inconsistent and squirrely as I use a VPN and then a fixed IP address to access the site.  Sometimes I do and don't receive 403 errors, other times the screen is just white.  This may be because some of the settings in the IIS Manager are not cleared out, so I have the following questions:

1. Is there a way to reset (zero out) the IP access control settings after each
   "Entry" IP address is removed in the IIS Manager?
2. When you use Web.Config for IP access control, do you need to open the IIS Manager and specify -->Edit Features Settings--> Allow (Access for unspecified clients)?
3. Do I need a Deny somewhere in the Web.Config?
4. What happens when Web.Config and IIS Manager have the same IP addresses listed for access control (I think it results in conflicts)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, IIS contains the same setting for IP restrictions. You could set it by using IIS management console or web.config.

More details about how to set it ,you could refer to below steps:

1.Open IIS management console and locate your web site and select the IP restrictions.

[image]

2.Click the edit feature setting and change access for unspecified clients to deny.

[image]

3.Click allow entry... and add some ip address to the specific ip address

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, I updated the question now that I am using Web.Config, and originally used IIS Manager.